# Tag names for applications and concepts

Tags: discussion, tags

Elementary OS includes applications with generic names such as Calendar, Files, Music, etc.

It is natural that this site will have a tag for each of these applications. The most obvious name for these tags is the name of the application, but since these are generic words, this conflicts with the general concept.

Tags are a way to classify posts. They are not search keywords; tags should have a single meaning. If I'm looking for a way to do something in the Files application, I'll use the “Files application” tag (example: [1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-can-i-select-a-file-without-it-opening)). If I'm looking for a way to work with files, I'll use the “files concept” tag (example: [1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-can-i-quickly-search-and-index-files)).

For simplicity there should be a consistent way to distinguish between application tags and concept tags. Note that tag names will always be styled in lowercase. Some possibilities include:

- plain tag name for the application, other formulation for the concept. For example: [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) for support questions about Pantheon Files, [file-management](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) for questions about file management in general.
- plain tag name for the concept, common suffix for the application. For example: [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) for questions about file management in general, [files-application](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files-application) for Pantheon Files.
- plain tag name for the concept, application full name for the application. For example: [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) for questions about file management in general, [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) for Pantheon Files.
- Blacklist the base name and only use compound tags. For example: [file-management](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) and [files-application](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files-application).

Moderators can rename tags, so if the naming convention needs to change, that's easy on the technical end. However we should pick a naming convention now, because disambiguating ambiguous tags gets more and more painful the more questions are concerned.

Comment: this issue was partly discussed in http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4/49 comments

Answer (score 2):

You raise some good points. As much as I understand the move to generic names (Files, Music, Calendar...) these will only conflict with the generic terms.

I would be in favor of:

1. using the generic terms for the generic concepts ([files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files), [calendar](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar), [music](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music))
2. prefix the elementary-specific apps with "Pantheon", for disambiguation ([pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files), [pantheon-calendar](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-calendar), [pantheon-music](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-music)), or maybe with "elementary" ([elementary-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-files), [elementary-calendar](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-calendar), [elementary-music](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-music))
3. have synonyms for the former names of the apps ([maya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maya), [noise](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise)).

With proper tag descriptions, this should all work out since the tag excerpt shows up in-place when one is typing a tag.

Comment: that's a fair request, but currently everything is tagged `files` and `terminal`, and it seems a little silly to change it all back - especially as `panthon-files` is harder for a user to type - especially a newbie that is unlikely to know it's real name and then use `files` in the wrong place. I think the current set up will do for now to be honest - with just `files` and just `terminal`. It's sensible to go for the most basic as the overall name when the complex name isn't used outside of support / dev etc.

Comment: Not silly at all IMO. We're in beta precisely to flesh out things for the final launch. If things are confusing at this point, there's no reason to keep them that way when we can identify a non-ambiguous alternative. Also, the point of tag redirects is precisely that users don't need to type the `pantheon-` (or whatever) prefix -- the redirection feature takes care of that. But we as a site get the benefit of having unambiguous canonical tags (to appear in the tag list, etc). As I see it, it's a win-win where we get both convenience on one side and clarity on the other.

Comment: But if most users are typing `files` why make that redirect? Why not make `pantheon-` the synonym that redirects?

Comment: That's all fine and dandy when they mean the same thing as we intended for the tag, but you can't guarantee that everyone will be in the same page, precisely because without the prefix, the tag is generic and ambiguous. If a user is asking a question about file management in general (or music, etc), what tag are they supposed to use? (cont.)

Comment: As gilles says, `file-management`... And note that it's already suggested:http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/tags/files/synonyms

Comment: (cont.) In fact, I'm sorry, I contradicted myself. I didn't mean for [tag:files] to redirect to [tag:pantheon-files]. Instead, as my answer states, they should be separate tags with proper descriptions, so that users can choose the proper one when adding a question. Note that that presents no loss of convenience, since the auto-complete feature allows users to type simply "files" and have the "pantheon-files" tag (along with the "files" one, of course) show up in the dropdown box.

Comment: So files would mean file-management? hmm

Comment: Yes. That's the correct equivalence, in semantic terms.

Comment: I have to say that is what [ubuntu.se] uses... But in ubuntu nautilus is commonly known as the name of it, so it is a little different. But there is an idea there. I also won't want to edit them to all have the new tag - @Gabriel says I'm doing too many edits atm (long story) :/ and I don't need another argument about that.

Comment: I would still say use the common name for the common item, but i think we need to wait a little to see if users are using the wrong tags.

Comment: Who does the edits is irrelevant - in fact, I'd be surprised if SE didn't provide a mechanism to rename tags. As for waiting to see, why would that change what is the preferred tag nomenclature? There is a semantic rationale for doing this change, not merely a confusion-prevention one.

Comment: What is the benifit of pantheon-files over files then?

Comment: Clarity/unambiguity, as I said above. We can discuss this further in chat if you want. This comment thread is already way too long...