# What tag should we use for questions about files?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) has been made a synonym of [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files), and the tag wiki for [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) describes it as being about Pantheon Files.

The thing is, many questions have been tagged [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) but were actually about files (the concept), not Files (the application).

What name should we keep? [Tag names for applications and concepts](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/tag-names-for-applications-and-concepts) raised this point already. It was inconclusive due to low views and voting, though the only opinion that was expressed was to use generic terms for the concepts ([files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) about files) and prefixes for the applications ([pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) about Files).

Either way, please undo the synonym while we sort this out (this requires moderator intervention), then we can retag any [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) question that's about Files to [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files). Then, if we decide to make [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) about files, a moderator can rename tags as desired.

Comment: I have removed the synonym until a decision is reached.

Comment: I'm not sure what the distinction is. Surely questions about files the concept involve files the app

Comment: @DanielForé Plenty of questions about files don't involve Files in any way: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/697 http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/333 http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/328 http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/307 …

Comment: @Gilles Well the first one is definitely related to files since it has "file chooser module" :p But the second one, I would just say is incorrectly tagged. It's about Scratch.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be preferably to change the [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files) tag's description to being about file the objects, and keeping [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) about the application.

Comment: As I've already expressed in the question linked above, I agree with your stance.

Comment: @waldyrious Action has been taken based on votes cast here. You should mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I would gladly, but I'm not OP :)

Comment: Oh, wow, whoops. Hey @Gilles, do the thing!

Comment: While we're at it, [tag:file-manager] should be renamed [tag:file-managers] and unset as a synonym for [tag:pantheon-files], as it will most likely be useful for people using different file managers, such as Nemo, Thunar, Nautilus, etc.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend that the "files" and "pantheon-files" tags remain synonyms. Otherwise there's a whole lot of re-tagging to do. Pretty much everything under that tag refers to Files the app. Also, elementary.io currently points to the "files" tag. And the tag wiki itself even says that the "files" tag is about Files the app.

Questions about the filesystem itself should be tagged "filesystem". I think that would make it more clear that the tag isn't referring to Files the app.

I would also like to mention that users are currently using this tag to refer to files the app. Almost every question tagged "files" refers to files the app. Retagging all of the existing questions won't stop people from using the "files" tag to refer to Files the app.

Comment: Moderators can rename tags, so that's not a problem. I would recommend not to keep an ambiguous [tag:files]. Why would questions about *files* be tagged [tag:filesystem]? That name would be really hard to discover.

Comment: Even if moderators couldn't rename tags, work for site maintainers (unless if it's a ludicrous amount) shouldn't be an argument preventing improvements for site users. I for one would be willing to help in the re-tagging if that were necessary.

Comment: @Gilles I don't think the tag "files" means anything outside of files the app. The only questions tagged "files" that aren't about Files the app are about the linux filesystem or about another app or are mistagged and have nothing in particular to do with files the app or the filesystem at all. I don't think users are going to stop tagging things as "files" because you rename everything existing as "pantheon-files".

Comment: I've given several examples of questions that are about files. They aren't mistagged unless you start with the assumption that [tag:files] is about Files. The fact that the tag name “files” is heavily used to mean Files is an argument to make that official. But claiming that there are no questions about files is nonsense.

Comment: @Gilles you listed four (sorry misread): two that *were* actually about Files the app, one about Scratch, and another that was about the Linux filesystem and also closed.